# Is it natural to say "the cup is on the edge of the table, push it in please"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

My children are too small and they don't understand much about carefulness.

For example 1, they sometimes put the cup on the edge of a table like this.

[image]

And I want them to push the cup toward the middle of the table.

Is it natural to say?

- "**the cup is on the edge of the table, push it to the middle please**"
- "**the cup is on the edge of the table, push it into the middle please**"
- "**the cup is on the edge of the table, push it in please**"

For example 2, they sometimes put the cup on the edge of a counter which has 1 side connecting to a wall like this.

[image]

And I want them to push the cup toward the wall.

Is it natural to say?

- "**the cup is on the edge of the counter, push it all the way to the wall please**"
- "**the cup is on the edge of the table, push it all the way in please**"
- "**the cup is on the edge of the counter, push it all the way to the corner please**"

Comment: I would say "Don't put it by the edge! It could fall.", and then move it in yourself to show what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would most likely say something like

> Move/Push the cup **away from the edge** please.

Saying "push it in please" or "push it all the way in please" doesn't really make sense in this context: you would say that if, for example, you were pressing a button or attaching something into a socket.

If you want more succinct sentences, you could also use the preposition  ***towards***:

> Push it **towards** the middle please.
>
> Push it **towards** the wall please.
>
> Push it **towards** the corner please.

Comment: Agreed. I've also said/heard it said to push it away from the edge.